How can I extract [object Object] that I received from my request.query
I am trying to send a object to my backend through a object, but when I try to extract that I am getting [object Object].
These are the filters:
public filters: { [key: string]: any } = {};
And I add a key with a object as value to it as filter:
this.filters[key] = {my object};
Now in the backend when I try to get the object like this:
export async function myFunction(
    request: Request,
    response: Response,
) {
    const chartFilters = request.query?.chartFilters;
}

the chartFilters will display [object Object].
I've tried lots of things but kept getting errors.
Hope someone can help me.

request.query gets values from the URL query string, doesn't it?  What is the URL being used in the request?  Does the URL contain the string "[object Object]"?  The query string is for key/value pairs, not complex objects.

You are doing this this.filters[key] = {my object}; on the frontend side? If yes, your url is most certainly already wrong when it leaves your client and there is no way of getting the original data on the server, because it's just not contained in the url. Check in the network inspector what the URL you are sending really looks like

I have checked it, I guess it became a string because of its complexity.
  { entity: [ 'meester jan', 'dorro', 'mussie' ], chartFilters: '[object Object]' }
Is there a alternative to sent this object with a get request?

@JipVeerbeek: If it has to be a GET request then I suppose you'd either send the values individually or serialize the object to a string and send that string.  Make sure the values are also URL-encoded, as complex strings can break the URL.

Try using JSON.stringify(/* object here */) in the generator (route? response?) of this Request that you're trying to get your chartFilters... Then you can use JSON.parse(/*  stringified object here */) to retrieve your object on the other end.
